# How does Laravel implement clean URL and redirect them to Controllers

Tags: php, laravel

The title says it pretty well... How does Laravel implement clean URL and redirect them to the right Controllers.

Some frameworks like CakePHP use *.htaccess* to redirect everything to a FrontController which then dispatch the requests but laravel doesn't use *.htaccess* so i am bit confused.

Comment: Actually Laravel does use a `.htaccess` file, see [the source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess).

Comment: @Rubens, your right. It does use it in the 'Public' folder but what about the other folders. In version 3, there is application, bundles, Laravel and storage folders which doesn't have .htaccess

Comment: In both version (3 or 4) your document root will be the public folder. So this is the only directory accessible from the outside world, the other directories are never intended to be accessible from the outside world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel use the concept of "routing", where all clean url are *usually* defined and mapped to something that will resolve to a view, such as controller action, anonymous functions, plain string, etc...

Each request will be caught by a file located at: `public/index.php` (that is done by a .htaccess file located at the same location). That index.php file will boostrap or *illuminate* the Laravel framework, and Laravel will run your code. How is it done? *Routing*.

The routing configuration is stored in a file located at `app/routes.php` where a route might look as follows:

```
Route::get('/users',            'UserController@showUsers');
Route::get('/users/create',     'UserController@createUser');
Route::post('/users/create',    'UserController@processCreateUser');
Route::get('/users/edit/{id}',  'UserController@createUser');
Route::post('/users/edit/{id}', 'UserController@processCreateUser');
```

More information about routing can be read at [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing). I strongly recommend you to read the docs since routing are quite powerful in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel sites use the `public/` folder as their document root. You'll find the `.htaccess` file in there.

Comment: how does Laravel define that public/ is the root folder of the application?

Comment: You'll need to set the document root as `public/` in Apache.

Comment: @Gab, you should double check the docs regarding installation instructions. They clearly says: *It is recommended that you either set the public folder as your site's documentRoot (also known as a web root) or to place the contents of public into your site's root directory and place all of Laravel's other files outside the web root.* Check that part: [Installation paths](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration) Saying that, is your responsibility to define the `public` directory as your document root via your web server.